# Getting int value from a series in a dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Suppose I have a df like this-

```
A        B
1  {'meta': 3}
2  {'meta': 3}
3  {'tera': 3}
```

I want to retrieve the int value from column-B.
Desired Dataframe-

```
A B
1 3
2 3
3 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column B is a dict, so let's get the value corresponding to the key.

As we don't know the key name, take the first value.

It's already an integer. No conversion needed.

```py
df["B"] = df["B"].map(lambda x: list(d.values())[0])
```

Comment: last is value `tera`

Comment: I forgot hat point. Your only keys will be meta and tera ?

Comment: Maybe best ask OP, no idea.

Comment: I could have any value there before :

Comment: Edited to work with any key.
Will work as soon as the dict in column B consists of a key associated to a integer value.